# What limits are there on the Civilization V demo?

Tags: civilization-5

How is the Civ 5 demo limited, how long is it, and is the 4+ GB installation worth it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Civ 5 demo is a single map that will be the same each time you play it, has 3 civilizations to choose from, and you can only play for 100 turns.

Comment: I've played through the demo three times now - once with each available civilization. It disappoints me every time when it ends. I was not planning on buying the game yet, but it's more tempting than ever now.

Comment: Does it have multiplayer?

Comment: @BlueRaja No, Single player only.